# TLSv1.3 Not Supporting in iOS 17 - iOS

Tags: ios, websocket, tls1.3, socketrocket

I am trying to set my TLS version as 1.3 but unfortunately I am not able to do that.
where can I set my TLS version in the code?

Before my server configuration was TLSv1.2 , in this I can connect the web-socket without any issue.
After my server TLS version has been changed to TLSv1.3, now I am not able to connect the web-socket by using this Socket rocket Library.

Using Xcode 15.1, ios 17.1, Socket Rocket Library.

```
SRWebSocket *newWebSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:mutableRequest];

newWebSocket.delegate = self;
[newWebSocket open];
```

Got the error response below,

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-9836 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9836, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

Expecting Web-socket connection to happen for the server which is configured as TLSv1.3.

Comment: I don't think it is anything to do with iOS 17.  It is more likely that the library you are using does not support tls1.3.  I would suggest that you migrate to iOS's native [websockets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/3181171-websockettaskwithurl)

Comment: Thanks for you reply will check this 

Comment: @Paulw11 I have migrated my library to iOS's native websocket  library, but now the delegate method is not called after a successful web-socket connection.
Initiating delegate as well -  webSocketTask.delegate = self;

- (void)webSocket:(NSURLSessionWebSocketTask *)webSocket 
didReceiveMessage:(NSURLSessionWebSocketMessage *)message {

Comment: I would suggest you ask another question and include the relevant code.

Comment: @Paulw11 WebSocket handshake completed but delegate methods not triggering,
However, despite the handshake completion, I am encountering an issue where the delegate methods associated with the WebSocket task are not being triggered. 
 webSocketTask = [session webSocketTaskWithRequest:[mutableRequest copy]];
     
    // Set the delegate for the data task
        webSocketTask.delegate = self;
      [webSocketTask resume];

Comment: Yes. So you said. You should [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), including relevant code and information.

Answer (score 0):

That library doesn't appear to support TLS 1.3.

iOS has native support for WebSockets now. You might like to use that instead.